# VBA Form returns Compile error method or data member not found when label clearly exist

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do it use a label to pop up, via a click, a user form, enter data and unload it into the label but VBA does not seem to recognize the label. I can make the form appear, but when I want to feed to data to the label the code crashed with the error message "Compile error method or data member not found"

```
Private Sub ok_Click()
    Sheet1.faktnr = Me.faktnr
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

That's all the code, the label and textbox is named faktnr. This is probably a silly question but I feel stupified by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub ok_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("faktnr") = Me.faktnr
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: It solved that issue it seems, now it complains about "Me.faktnr". Gotta doubbleconfurm that I named the textbox correctly.

EDIT: Seems like I typoed, getting another error I can work with now - thanks!

Comment: Well, if you're happy with my answer, please do mark it as such. Thanks.